# Is it possible to locate which file a code is coming from in "Inspect Element"

Tags: html

So when I inspect an element of code like this

[image: http://img.ezlocal.com/j/Step-3-Modify-Code-1.png]

Say I click on a line that says

```
<div class="foo">bar</div>
```

Is there a way I can find out what file this code is coming from?

IE: home.html or new.html

Is this possible? I know it shows for the CSS.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

The files are on a ftp server

Answer (score 1):

For example, check at the bottom path from inspected element to the first parent `html` (either the top one, or iframe) tag, click on it.
[image]

Than on the right side select `properties` of the `html` and look at `baseURI`
[image]

Comment: It doesn't say the file name though

Comment: @c_sharper_ if you are looking at `.html` page - it will show the `file.html` in URI. If you are talking about SEO + mod_rewrite things - what to you call the `filename` in that case?

Comment: It just says www.something.com/dothis .. but it doesn't show which file

Comment: @c_sharper_ what do you mean by the `file`?? if you have dynamic pages, there are not specific files, only URIs. filename is accessible only when you have static pages or server-side scripts which do not use mod_rewrite things. Give the link that you are interested in.

Comment: @c_sharper_ as I told you, it will not show you filename in the filesystem of the server. your browser knows only what server tells him. All that you can know for the link is URI, you can not find what the local filename is. If inspected element is in iframe than you can find URI of that iframe, not more.